# Using Semiconductors alone

Tags: semiconductor-physics

We always use N-type semiconductor and P-type semiconductor together,like diode,transistor,etc. can we use N-type or P-type semiconductor alone in an electrical circuit because they both have free charge carriers?

Comment: You could, but metallization has lower resistivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

- A Schottky diode uses a metal-semiconductor junction to form a diode with (typically) a lower forward voltage and faster switching behavior than a PN junction diode.
- A MOSFET uses a field applied to a semiconductor to form a narrow region with behavior much like the other type. I.e. In a p-channel MOSFET you start with n-type material and apply a field to make a narrow region near the surface behave like p-type.

Answer (score 0):

@ThePhoton has given an excellent answer. I would like only to add that we are using semiconductors not for their charged carriers - for passing current their are by far inferior to metals. What is really useful is the **semiconductor junctions**, i.e. the interfaces between different types of semiconductors or semiconductors and metals (or possibly other materials).

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one class of semiconductor devices, which has not yet been mentioned here:

**Photoconductive detectors** or **photoresistors** are also semiconductor-based (typically CdS or CdSe) devices that don't contain a p-n junction. Light excites electron hole pairs and therefore changes the conductivity of the semiconductor material. These are common as simple cost-effective light sensors, e.g. in street lamps.